# Image description as popup in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am making an ASP.NET website where i have sort of a static image gallery. Now when i click on an image in this gallery i want to show a pop up containing text (10-15 lines) describing the image.

How can I achieve this? I don't have much idea as to how I should proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps to archive this.

**First step** is to make the pop up window using css.

Many examples on google about that.

[Search on google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=css+popup+window&oq=css+popu&gs_l=serp.3.1.0l10.1351.3270.0.4781.8.8.0.0.0.0.113.740.7j1.8.0.ciatsh..0.0...1.YnHFQ3hbOiQ)

[Open Css popup](http://www.pat-burt.com/web-development/how-to-do-a-css-popup-without-opening-a-new-window/)

[Easy Css pop up](http://bucarotechelp.com/design/csseasy/97112700.asp)

The **Second step** is to make your `javascript` to open it and show your actually text. If you use a library like jQuery you can make many thinks more easy, but if you wish pure javascript can you also make it work.

For example on the last link 'Easy Css pop up', the javascript to open it is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseover="ShowPop('pop');"
                 onMouseout="HidePop('pop');"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

So what you do is to render your text of your images into the div that have this css popup and then you place a code like that on every image to open the correct popup.

Of cource you can find a ready to use gallery like the http://highslide.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or simply [open page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) with javascript

Comment: Did not tag with jQuery, and the open page is not even close to good solution.